# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "Deals" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Deals_AirlineCodes_AirlineCodesId"

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, pgadmin-4

I am working .net core 3.1 project with postgresql.

I have two tables Deals and AirlineCodes

I tried to add a new column (for add AirlineCodes ) into Deals table.

I tried with below codes.

Deal.cs

```
 public int AirlineId { get; set; }

 public Airline Airline { get; set; }
```

Airline.cs

```
public class Airline
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id { get; private set; }
        public string AirlineCode { get; set; }
        public string AirlineFullName { get; set; }
    }
```

DbContext.cs

```
 public DbSet<Airline> AirlineCodes { get; set; }
 public DbSet<Deal> Deals { get; set; }
```

And I get this error

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[20102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (322ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
      ALTER TABLE "Deals" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_Deals_AirlineCodes_AirlineCodesId" FOREIGN KEY ("AirlineCodesId") REFERENCES "AirlineCodes" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Failed executing DbCommand (322ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='300']
ALTER TABLE "Deals" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_Deals_AirlineCodes_AirlineCodesId" FOREIGN KEY ("AirlineCodesId") REFERENCES "AirlineCodes" ("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE;
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 23503: insert or update on table "Deals" violates foreign key constraint "FK_Deals_AirlineCodes_AirlineCodesId"
```

Why this error occur?

Does anyone know the solution? Help me to create a new column with AirlineId into DealsTable.

Comment: You can't add a new non-nullable column with no default value.

Comment: Okay. So I have to delete all rows in Deals Table and Add a new column??

Comment: Or make the new column nullable at first, then figure out the data for it, and then make it non-nullable.

Comment: Okay This is a good one. Thank you